# Active Directory Domain Trust - User Audit: AD-Users from Dom-A in AD-Groups in Dom-B

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship

For our trusted corporation workflow we had installed some AD-Domain Trusts like that:

One Active Directory "Master-Domain" with all AD-Users:
Dom-A.extra.com

Five extra Active Directory's for different Corporations (corp-domains), for computers and Groups for Fileserver and Domain-Logon Access.

```
Dom-1.intra  
Dom-2.intra  
Dom-3.intra  
Dom-4.intra  
Dom-5.intra
```

Our working "User<->Group" mapping:
user (from master-domain) is in a local-Domain-security-group (from corp-domain).

To audit my users and list their permissions out I need to see all groups for it.
like:

```
user-1 (from master-domain..) has groupmembership:  
Domain: Dom-A.extra.com  
Group: all-chat  
Group: all-pub  
Group: all-vpn  
Domain: Dom-1.intra  
Group: filesrv_A  
Domain: Dom-2.intra  
Group: remote_B  
Domain: Dom-3.intra  
Group: filesrv_C
```

In the user-tab `groupmembership` I can only see domain-local groups but not the remote groups from the domain-trusts.
If I look in the domain-trusted groups I see the ad-users, but this is not really audit like.

I tested some `ps` commands like `get-adgroupmember`, but all of them filter for user (in trusted domain there is no user) or show only local groups (on master-domain).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty simple really. Audit all groups in all domains.

Comment: is it possible to get all group (and members) from "master-domain" Server?

Comment: No. Only universal group members are replicated to all domain controllers in a forest. If a domain is external to the forest, then none would be replicated.